# 802.1X Mac El Capitan profile delete

Tags: macos

How to delete 802.1x profile on Mac?

[image]Because I have no ability to connect to the "eduroam" wifi.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it the following way on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6:

1. Go to System Preferences/Profiles
2. Click on Eduroam and remove the profile

Now if you go to System Preferences/Network,
then click Advanced and 802.1X, it should be gone.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 11):

Edit file `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist` with superuser privilege, or just move it to elsewhere if there's only one 802.1X profile.

How to do it?

- To edit, in terminal.app, execute (one line!) `sudo nano /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist`, then enter Mac login password if requested. In nano editor, saving is Ctrl+O and exiting is Ctrl+X.
- To move, in terminal.app, execute (one line!) `sudo mv /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist-BACKUP`, then enter Mac login password if requested.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

OS X 10.6/10.7/10.8

If you are unable to remove Eduroam profile in point 6 or user keep getting server time out or invalid login during authentication. This is achieved by deleting System preferences for network and wireless.

Make sure WIFI is turned off and you have administrative privileges. For 10.5 or 10.6, using Finder navigate to: /Users//Library/Preferences/

Find and delete the following files.

1. com.apple.eap.profiles.plist
2. NetworkInterfaces.plist

For 10.7 or 10.8, using Finder navigate to: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ Find and delete the following files.

1. com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist
2. com.apple.network.identification.plist
3. com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
4. NetworkInterfaces.plist

Finally

In KeyChain Access   – Find entries containing eduroam, rad0, rad1 and delete all.

Restart your machine.

Comment: In mac osx sierra high, I had to go to `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`. I opted to manually editing the required files with `sudo nano` in the Terminal

Comment: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist was the root of my problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: @HamZa Completing detail: Edit `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist` with superuser privilege, or just move it to elsewhere if there's only one 802.1X profile. For the latter case, e.g. in terminal, execute `sudo mv /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist-BACKUP` then enter Mac login password if requested.